# Merge a range of revisions with Git or TortoiseGit

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I'm trying to merge changes made in the master branch of my repository into a development branch using git or TortoiseGit.  I know that I can just use either a git [pull](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-pull.html) or a [merge](http://schacon.github.com/git/user-manual.html#how-to-merge), but this merges in too many changes into the development branch at once, and makes it more difficult to resolve conflicts.

If I was using SVN or TortoiseSVN, I could just merge in changes from the main trunk a little bit at a time instead of all at once, using a range of revisions for the merge.  Could I do something similar with git or TortoiseGit?  That is, could I merge in a range of revisions into my development branch instead of merging in all changes at once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Summary

Using Git from the command line, you can rebase `feature` onto `master`:

```bash
git rebase master feature

# Now force push the changes to your remote
git push <remote> feature --force
```

**Warning**: ***do not carelessly force push rebased (rewritten) commits/branches*** if you share those commits/branches with other people, because you'll cause conflicts with any changes they've based off the older versions of the commits/branches. It's possible to work this way in (very) small teams, but good coordination is required.

You can also use the [`--onto`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html#_options) flag to specify a **range**, where `<start commit>` is the exclusive start of the range:

```
git rebase --onto master <start commit> feature
```

Finally, [`cherry-pick`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) can actually accept a range of arguments. With the `master` branch checked-out:

```bash
# Cherry-pick all commits from `<start commit>`
# exclusive, not included) to feature:
git cherry-pick <start commit>..feature
```

### Detailed Explanation

My original goal was to be able to sync up my `feature` branch with changes made in `master`, but I didn't want to just merge in `master` because it caused too many conflicts that had to be resolved at once. I just wanted to be able to merge in the changes gradually, so I could resolve the conflicts in smaller, more manageable pieces.

#### Enter `git rebase`

The best way to do that is in fact [`git rebase`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html). It's perfect, actually. What it will do is take all the commits that I've made in `feature` and ***make copies*** of those commits in the same order, except that it ***recommits them on top of the latest revision of the target branch***, which, in my case, was `master`.

This is significant for two reasons:

1. This is equivalent to merging `master` into `feature`. Why? Because `feature` is basically recreated on top of the most recent revisions of `master`…all of `master`'s commits now exist in the history of `feature`, including the commits in `master` that `feature` didn't have yet.
2. Git reapplies the commits ***one at a time***, in order, so if there are any conflicts, they're introduced into the process in several smaller, more manageable pieces, one at a time, which is exactly what I was hoping to do!

This is what it looks like visually (examples adapted from [official Linux Kernel Git documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html#_description)):

```
      A---B---C feature
     /
D---E---F---G master
```

In the above example, commits `F` and `G` where made on `master` since I branched `feature` off of it. What I want to do is sync those changes to `feature`:

```
git rebase master feature
```

Now my branches look like this:

```
              A'--B'--C' feature
             /
D---E---F---G master
     \
      A---B---C (no branch)
```

Commits `A` through `C` have been recreated as `A'` through `C'` on top of the latest version of `master`.  The old commits still exist in the Git repo, but because there's no branch pointer that's referencing them, they'll eventually be garbage collected by Git.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do that. Let's say that your repository looks like this:

```
      master
 A---[B]
  \
   \                       feature
    (c1)---(c2)---(...)---(c100)
```

You want to merge the `feature` branch into `master`, but there's a lot of commits there. Instead, let's make a new branch `tmp` that points to an earlier commit along `feature`:

```
 git branch tmp c2

 A---[B]
  \
   \        tmp               feature
    (c1)---[(c2)]---(...)---(c100)
```

Now `tmp` points to `c2`. Now we can merge just the commits `c1...c2` into master without regard to `c3...c100`:

```
 git checkout master
 git merge tmp
```

Now, move `tmp` to the next batch of commits (we need `-f` to `force` it, since `tmp` already exists). For instance, if we want to move to `c6` now, use that:

```
 git branch -f tmp c6
```

Repeat this until all the commits you want to merge are in.

Comment: Note that you don’t necessarily need to create a named branch for that, you can just as well run `git merge <commit-hash>` to merge some specific commit into the current branch. And instead of `git branch -f tmp c6` you can also move the pointer using `git reset --hard c6`, or even do a fast-forward merge `git merge --ff c6`.

Comment: @poke I like the idea of not having to create a temporary branch to merge in commits, but the problem with using `git merge <commit-hash>` is that it only merges in a single revision, not a range of them (correct?).  If I had 100 revisions to merge in, wouldn't I have to use that command 100 times?

Comment: @John this solution seems like it would work, but I'm not entirely comfortable with having to create a temporary branch (multiple times) just to merge in changes gradually.

Comment: @ColdHawaiian I’ve written up a more lengthy explanation as a separate answer, hope it helps! :)

Comment: @ColdHawaiian Branches are there to be used that way, so that you can "hold your place". You can always delete the branch when you're done (git branch -D tmp). No one ever sees `tmp` since you won't push it, just `master`.

Answer (score 2):

*Note: John’s answer is correct; this is just a further explanation based on the follow-up questions in the comments – I just needed a bit more room :)*

> I like the idea of not having to create a temporary branch to merge in commits, but the problem with using `git merge <commit-hash>` is that it only merges in a single revision, not a range of them (correct?). If I had 100 revisions to merge in, wouldn't I have to use that command 100 times?

No, in Git, the history is always connected. So if you merge a commit into master, and between the common ancestor of `master` and that commit are more commits, those are completely preserved. Unlike SVN, Git keeps full references to previous commits (with an unlimited number of pointers, so you can merge multiple branches at once). So in the end, you will always see where a branch started, what happened on it, what was merged in between, and where it was merged back into the main branch – only the name (or rather *label*) of the branch is not kept (except in the auto merge text, if that counts ^^).

So your history can for example look like this:

```
* -- A -- * ---------- * ----- * -- * -- M [master]
      \
       \
        B1 -- B2 -- B3 -- B4 -- B5 -- B6 -- B7 -- B8 -- B9 [br]
```

Suppose you want to merge `B9` (the HEAD commit on the branch `br`) back into `M` which is where the `master` branch is pointing at. With a direct merge, you will get this (`#` are merge commits):

```
* -- A -- * ---------- * ----- * -- * -- M ---------------- # [master]
      \                                                    /
       \                                                  /
        B1 -- B2 -- B3 -- B4 -- B5 -- B6 -- B7 -- B8 -- B9 [br]
```

So even if you remove the branch pointer `br`, you can still see all the commits that occured on that separate branch.

Or if you want to merge in multiple steps, you can easily merge it like this:

```
* -- A -- * -- * -- * -- * -- M -- #---------- # --------------- # --- # [master]
      \                           /           /                 /     /
       \                         /           /                 /     /
        B1 -- B2 ------------ - B3 -- B4 -- B5 -- B6 -- B7 -- B8 -- B9 [br]
```

And again, you can always look back at the whole tree, and all the separate commits that were made on the branch – even if you remove the branch (which again, just removes the pointer).

So maybe this explanation will also show you that you don’t necessarily need to make merges in such small steps. You will never lose information during a merge, as you can always look back on all commits.